# Undoing an update to a database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

A small winform app that I've written has a databound datagridview on the form.  It's bound to a datatable.  The user can change data displayed in the datagridview and hit the Save button to update the underlying database.  I do this with an `dataTable.AcceptChanges()` statement.

I'd like to implement an 'undo' feature so that, if after updating, the user changes their mind, they can undo the changes by hitting an Undo button.

I was thinking that I'd just basically make a copy of the original data as it's loaded into the datagridview and just compare that to the underlying datatable after the user has made their changes. So, when there is a difference between the 'original' data and the data after updating, I'd just update the database with what's in the original data.  I hope this makes sense.

My question, though, is whether this is a good idea to accomplish this?  I guess it seems straightforward to just keep a copy of the original data and use it to undo changes that were made, I was just wondering if there are other ways/mechanisms to do this.

The program uses a model built database-first with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plan to implement a `undo` as session based, as long as `SqlConnection` remains open.

You can create a `Transaction Point` using [`SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then if you simply want to discard the data (undo) then call the `Rollback()` or `Dispose()` or to save data permanently call the `Commit()`  method on `SqlTransaction`

---

A way on how you can implement . . .

1. Start Transaction() /Create SavePoint
2. Each time a user issues `Save` command, create a `SavePoint()` (you can push it on the `Stack`
3. Each time a undo command is issed, Pop the SavePoint name and do a rollback.

---

From entity framework point of view . . .

Until you call `SaveChanges()` method, all the changes are local, let the user make as much change as he likes, and do a `SaveChanges()` only when you need to make those changes permanently.

Comment: Ah!  That sounds like what I'm looking for.  Since I'm using Entity Framework, I'll research transaction points with regards to EF5.0 and see what I can find out.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: unless you have multiple users editing the same data (this may not apply as it seems there is only one user).

Comment: @daryal Correct.  This app will be only used by one person.  But, that's good to keep in mind.  Thanks!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Thanks for the extra information.  I greatly appreciate it.  I think you've given me enough to run with.  Thanks, again!